# Injecting user registration steps into IdentityServer3 SSO process

Tags: asp.net-mvc, single-sign-on, thinktecture-ident-server

I'm looking to employ Thinktecture's [IdentityServer3](https://github.com/identityserver/IdentityServer3) solution as a SSO service across multiple web application the organisation makes available to external users.

Taking the [MVC Authentication sample](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/MVC%20Authentication) as a starting point I'm looking at bolting on a registration process for new users to capture extra details when they first come to use the systems. This process is common across all the services we provide so I wish to bundle it alongside our SSO service.

Is there an elegant way to inject extra business logic into the IdentityServer3 core service? Basically if they're a new user I need to redirect them to some registration pages before flicking them back authenticated to the web application that they originally wanted to authenticate against.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both docs

https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/advanced/userService.html

and samples

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/CustomUserService

cover this.

Comment: Thank you, not sure how I missed that sample!

Comment: Just for anyone else that stumbles across this looking for a solution: To share authentication cookies custom pages must reside at the same route as where IdentityServer3 is registered - https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/676#issuecomment-69137559 - the sample shows how to achieve this via routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes() in RegisterRoutes and route decorations in controllers e.g. [Route("core/externalregistration")]